# FTP Can't see the content of some folders

Tags: ftp, filezilla, privileges, home-directory

I am using Filezilla server and I've created a user with all privileges on specific folder and sub folders, but unfortunately, when LIST some directories it shows that the folder is empty even though it is not, and even though I have full privileges on this folder!

the following is the log from FileZilla Server

```
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 230 Logged on
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> SYST
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> FEAT
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> PWD
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> TYPE I
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 200 Type set to I
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> PASV
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,11,108,107,226,70)
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> MLSD
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:14 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 226 Successfully transferred "/"
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:18 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> MKD New directory
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:18 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 450 Internal error creating the directory.
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:18 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> MKD /New directory
(000040)1/9/2016 16:58:18 PM - linux_server (10.11.108.107)> 450 Internal error creating the directory.
```

Please note that I have tried several FTP clients, with the same problem.
Is it possible that File sharing in windows may effect the ftp connection in some how?

Test1: I tried to move all files inside the inaccessible directory to another directory with the same name exactly and then deleted the old folder, and then it works! is it possible that there is some configuration from windows to restrict the access to that delete folder? any way I still have some inaccessible directories (other than the solved one).

Comment: So try to upload a file to the directory and then do an LS command and see if that uploaded file is listed. If it is but the other files are not, check the security attributes of these files from the server to see what the different may be at this level. Perhaps the Service account has restricted ACL permissions on the files that were CUT to this mailbox location and retained their permissions where they were cut from whereas a newly uploaded file to this will show you have the ACL permissions should be set so the FTP accounts with access and the FTP service security can access, etc.

Comment: when I try to upload `Could not write to transfer socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted` from FileZilla Client logs, so I can't upload any files, not making new directories (just in some folders) I don't know whether the Names may have any impact?

Comment: Check whether you have it setup for active or passive and connect with the client via that same method. Ensure you have applicable ports opened up for your configuration as well.

Comment: Ensure the user that your FileZilla *server* is running as has proper (write/create) access in the folder that's acting as the FTP root, as well as any sub folders that may already exist.